# How to fix this issue with Android Studio avd

Tags: android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I can't enable the graphics option when creating a new avd, and this happens later.

This is what happens when I try zooming:

[image: zoomed]

Comment: use zoom out / in option to reset.

Comment: I tried bro, buts it just zooms in and does not come back to normal while zooming out

Comment: I fixed it, it was an issue with the windows scaling set to 150%  in display settings. It works fine with 125% scaling